# Cannot push item to javascript array using ng-click if the ng-model does not change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I am able to add the items (through html input) to un-ordered list dynamically through ng-click event handling. This happens whenever i change the input textbox value. But if i click the add button without updating the textbox, the input textbox value is not added to list.

```
<body>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module("myShoppingList", []); 
        app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
            $scope.products = ["Milk", "Bread", "Cheese"];
            $scope.addItem = function () {
                $scope.products.push($scope.addMe);
            }    
        });
    </script>

    <div ng-app="myShoppingList" ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in products">{{x}}</li>
      </ul>
      <input ng-model="addMe">
      <button ng-click="addItem()">Add</button>
    </div>

    <p>Write in the input field to add items.</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `track by $index` like following. `AngularJS` does not allow duplicates in a `ng-repeat` directive. You will get error if you try to do that.

If you want to allow duplicate, you need to change your code like following.

```
   <li ng-repeat="x in products track by $index">{{x}}</li>
```

Example

```js
var app = angular.module("myShoppingList", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.products = ["Milk", "Bread", "Cheese"];
  $scope.addItem = function() {
    $scope.products.push($scope.addMe);
  }
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myShoppingList" ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in products track by $index">{{x}}</li>
      </ul>
      <input ng-model="addMe">
      <button ng-click="addItem()">Add</button>
    </div>
    <p>Write in the input field to add items.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It solved my problem.